# Listbox Selected Item to array

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a DataTable with 2 columns called "ID" and "Software" that I have used as a DataSource for a lst_Software multiselect listbox.

I'm trying to gather the ID for all the selected items in that have been selected and place that in an int[] array.

**Listbox setup:**

```
lst_Software.DataSource = software;  //software is a DataTable
lst_Software.DisplayMember = "Software";
lst_Software.ValueMember = "ID";
```

**I've tried below**

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < lst_Software.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
    list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(lst_Software.SelectedValue.ToString()));
}
int[] software = list.ToArray();
```

I'm finding that I'm only getting the first selected value except it will not iterate through all...  I know why though.  I'm not using **i** to get passed through inside the for loop. I'm hoping someone can give me a direction to go to iterate through all the selected values.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SelectedValue` is just the first selected value. You need to use `SelectedItems`.

Comment: What if the control is a ListBox and not a ListVIew and does not have the SelectedItems attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `lst_Software.SelectedValue.ToString()` here in the loop so it only returns the one item. You have a for loop but you're not using the index variable. However, all of this is unnecessary really all you need is;

```
  var items = lst_Software.SelectItems;
```

As that property is already the list of selected items. From there you can cast/convert them as you please.